# array_diff return a string without an array

Tags: php, file, newline, array-difference, file-put-contents

I'm trying to clean my db

```
if($var == true){
    $db = file('db.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    shuffle($db);
    $db2 = file('db2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $cleaner = array_unique ($db);
    $final = array_diff ($cleaner, $db2);
    file_put_contents('db3.txt', $final);
}
```

it should put in db3.txt all users with a newline like:

Mike\nRobert\nJhon\nPolly

but it return all users attached between them

Comment: Welcome. Please read the help section on how to provide a [mcse]. Also please provide the test of db.txt and db2.txt. Lastly, your title suggests work on a database, however, your question concerns on working with arrays; I suggest you reword your question title.

Answer (score 0):

You could use implode for add  the newline

```
$comma_separated = implode("\n", $final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way,

```
if($var == true){
    $db = file('db.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    shuffle($db);
    $db2 = file('db2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $cleaner = array_unique ($db);
    $final = array_diff ($cleaner, $db2);
    $final = implode(PHP_EOL, $final_result); // implode it with PHP_EOL
    // put content to file with FILE_APPEND parameter but you can ignore if you wish
    file_put_contents('db3.txt', $final, FILE_APPEND); 
}
```